# Hiding a lot of rows in a table in the down side of a page

Tags: tables

I created a table that have more than 25 rows and it causes some of the rows become hidden by the end of the page. How I can urge it to automatically put some of the rows in the next page?

This is the type of the table I use:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Language setting
% Replace `english' with e.g. `spanish' to change the document language
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Set page size and margins
% Replace `letterpaper' with `a4paper' for UK/EU standard size
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\title{paper}
\author{Authors}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{\label{demo-table} Summary of the models that are investigated in Section 3.}
\scalebox{0.8}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}| }
\hline

\hline
\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\
\hline
Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline
Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline
Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames,RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\

\hline

\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please extend your code snippet to an MWE, a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem. In normal circumstances, when table is smaller than page, this should not happen.

Comment: WElcome to TeX.SE!! You'll probably want to take a look at the `tabularray` (and its environment  `longtblr`) or `longtable` packages.

Comment: @Zarko , The question is updated.

Comment: But his is still not an  MWE. Please extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\|end{document}.` as you can see in the  @Juan Castaño answer.

Comment: @Zarko , I edited. Is it what you meant?

Comment: Yes, now is better. Your error is evident: long table is inserted to float `figure` . NEVER EVER INSERT LONG TABLE IN FLOAT ENVIRONMENT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to say as you have not shown a complete compilable document, and we don't know the size of your page or the width of the text in all the cells. However, this could be an approach using the environment `longtblr` from the `tabularray` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3] See table \ref{demo-table} below.
\begin{longtblr}
[% caption and label
   caption={Summary of the models that are investigated in Section 3.},
   label={demo-table}   
]
{% format
   colspec={XX[0.5]X[2]X[1.3]XX},
   hlines,vlines,
   rowhead=1,
   cells={font=\footnotesize}
}% content
Model & Year & Input & Architecture(s) & Backbone(s) & Dataset(s)\\
Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, RGB Video Frames, RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\
Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, RGB Video Frames, RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\
Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, RGB Video Frames, RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\
Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, RGB Video Frames, RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\
Multi-branch \cite{ref} & 2018 & RGB Video Frames, RGB Video Frames, RGB Video Frames & CNN & C3D &  DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE, DR(eye)VE\\
\end{longtblr}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

It looks like this (I cut the margins in the picture so as not to waste space).
[image]

Comment: A culprit of OP problem is use longtable in float `figure`. See my comment above. +1 for nice redesign of OP table!

Comment: @Zarko, thanks!!!

Comment: I want to use your solution for a paper in the class of IEEETran but unfortunately the table is divided into two columns. How I can fix that?

Comment: @dtr43, it's probably better if you post this as a new question, with a MWE to show the issue.

Comment: @JuanCastaño , I asked the question ins the following page: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686712/a-long-table-in-ieeetran-class-is-divided-in-to-two-columns