# A long table in IEEETran class is divided in to two columns

Tags: tables, longtable, ieeetran

I have a long table and the class of my document is IEEETran but by using the solution introduced in this question [Hiding a lot of rows in a table in the down side of a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/684915), my table is represented in two columns wrongly. I need my table to be represented in my page and its remainder to be shown in the next page.

```
   \documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}


\begin{longtblr}
[% caption and label
   caption={Summary of models},
   label={demo-table}   
]
{% format
   colspec={XX[0.5]X[2]X[1.3]XX},
   hlines,vlines,
   rowhead=1,
   cells={font=\footnotesize}
}% content
\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\
\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\
\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\
 
\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\


\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\
\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s) \\

\centering Model& \centering Year & \centering Input & \centering Architecture(s) & \centering Backbone(s)  & Dataset(s)
\end{longtblr}
```

The following image shows the output (a remainders of the table are located in the following columns like texts but the overal form of the table is the same but some of the texts are outside of the frames of the table):

[image]

How I can fix the problem?

Comment: Does showed table content is close to what will real have ? Your  MWE produce a table which is height about 3/3 `\textheight`.

Comment: @Zarko , the question is updated.

Comment: Do you think you could fit the tabular on one page using table* [p]?  Those single word per line paragraphs are ugly at best.

Comment: @JohnKormylo ,  I need a table that has lines between rows and columns and based on the space that the text inside each cell of the table occupy, the table adaptively can manage that. Plus, I do not persist on using tabular type and any approach is acceptable. In other words, because the style of my paper is IEEETran, I need the table to be located in the center of the page and not in columns and also because the table is long, I need the remander of the table to be represented in the next page.

Comment: I prefer a code, which  generate something close to desired table, At least let be image  larger, that we can read content of cells.

Comment: @Zarko , I added a larger image.

Comment: Large image doesn't help. Rather provide more realistic code, which produce showed image, At least for one row, or better, few of them. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

- Your document example is not complete. Please make it compilable, as we already ask you in comment.
- Provided code fragment is full of clutter. Please make yourself more familiar with `tabularraY` package. It has well written documentation reach of illustration. You can find it in your package installation or in [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray?lang=en).
- Please make content of cells more realistic, so far in cells are only one word and consequently table occupy only 3/4 of column height.
- For receiving help, please help us to understood your problem, MWE below is based on guessing.
- For starting point see MWE below, which compilation result is far from what you show in image in question.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

    \begin{longtblr}[% caption and label
caption = {Summary of models},
  label = {demo-table}
                    ]{% format
                       hlines,vlines,
                       colspec = {ll X[l] X[0.7, j, cmd=\hskip 0pt] X[l]X[l]},
                       colsep  = 3pt,
                        cells  = {font=\footnotesize},
                       row{1}  = {m},
                       rowhead = 1,
                      }
% column header(s)
Model   & Year & Input & Architecture(s)    
                                & Backbone(s)   & Dataset(s) \\
% table body
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\

Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\

Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\

Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
Model   & Year & Input & CCN    & Custom        & Dataset 1  \\
    \end{longtblr}

\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```